# MongoDB slow $unwind and $group aggregation

Tags: database, mongodb, optimization, nosql, aggregation

im having some trouble with my MongoDB aggregation. I have documents like:

```
{
    _id: "123456",
    values: [
        {
            "value": "A",
            "begin":0,
            "end":1,
        }
        {
            "value": "B",
            "begin":1,
            "end":2,
        }
        {
            "value": "C",
            "begin":3,
            "end":7,
        }
    ],
    "name": "test"
}
```

And i want to count only the "value" in "values".
With some help i got the following aggregation:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$unwind: "$values"},
  {$group: {_id: "$values.value", count: {$sum: 1}}}
])
```

The problem is: it takes me about 20 seconds to get the result for 6k documents.
Is there anything i can do for optimication?

Greetings

Comment: How many documents do you have after the `unwind`? Is it common for a specific value to return multiple times inside one document?

Comment: I try to visualize it with MongoDB Compass and if i see it correct i get as many document "copies" as objects in the array. So the above example object would be 3 times there.

Comment: Unwind will split the document to the array items. This is correct. I ask because you say you have 6K, documents, but with this method, if each has 1000 items it is like analyzing 6M records...So I'm, trying to understand the average number of items on each document, and if items repeat on the same document

Comment: Yeah some documents are relatively big and they have sometimes near to 500 objects in the Array. I should have about 200-300 times more objects after unwind (because some arrays only have few objects). So is it normal that it takes that long?

Comment: There is no such thing as normal. It depends on the data. You want to analyze 180K documents, but their distribution is also relevant. How many values do you get on the answer?

Comment: Maybe you can also consider to change your document structure. Maybe saving the "unwound" state of the document is a better option. Depends on what are your other operations with this collection

Comment: The problem is i need this document structure. After the unwind i have 31949240 as i see.

Comment: Do you know the `value` values or do you need a generic solution?

Comment: I know all the values, so every value is from a pre defined set. If i undestand you correct. But there are i think 40+ possible values. (Dont know if this information is necessary)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$reduce` to make some pre-processing of the arrays. Then you can sum up:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $project: {
         values: {
            $reduce: {
               input: { $setUnion: "$values.value" },
               initialValue: [],
               in: {
                  $concatArrays: [
                     "$$value",
                     [{
                        value: "$$this",
                        count: {
                           $size: {
                              $filter: {
                                 input: "$values",
                                 cond: { $eq: ["$$values.value", "$$this"] },
                                 as: "values"
                              }
                           }
                        }
                     }]
                  ]
               }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   { $unwind: "$values" },
   { $group: { _id: "$values.value", count: { $sum: "$values.count" } } }
])
```

Often `$map` if faster than `$reduce` (actually `$concatArrays` makes it slow, see [Performance issue for $reduce vs. $map](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-53503)), try this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $project: {
         values: {
            $map: {
               input: { $setUnion: "$values.value" },
               as: "value",
               in: {
                  value: "$$value",
                  count: {
                     $size: {
                        $filter: {
                           input: "$values",
                           cond: { $eq: ["$$this.value", "$$value"] },
                        }
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   { $unwind: "$values" },
   { $group: { _id: "$values.value", count: { $sum: "$values.count" } } }
])
```

If you know the values beforehand then you can use `input: ["A", "B", "C"]`

instead of `input: { $setUnion: "$values.value" }`

Comment: Thanks for your help, i tried it and i can se that there are less documents but somehow i get a timeout if i try to run this command and a heap error in java :/

Comment: I tried to count the objects after the unwind just to see how many there are now and event then i get an error. How is this possible its obviously less data?

Comment: Did you try with `{ allowDiskUse: true }`?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately it did not change anything :/

Comment: I dont have the error if i used it in java but it takes 4 minutes for the response

Comment: Please see my update. `$project` might be even better, if you have many other fields which are not needed for the final result.

Comment: The projection and unwind operation is much faster now but its the group operation again thats slowing everything down :/

Comment: Maybe try `{ $sort: { "values.value": 1 } }` before the `$group`

Comment: Its the same it takes too long. I think maybe its a lot of data or a bad structure for this operation. But thank you for your time and help :)