# MongoDB indexes for Objects inside array

Tags: database, mongodb, indexing, nosql, aggregation

im working on an api and need fast queries for my MongoDB. I have objects like:

```
{     
    _id: "123456",     
    values: [         
            {             
                "value": "A",            
                "begin":0,             
                "end":1,         
            },
             {
                 "value": "B",
                 "begin":1,
                 "end":2,
             },
             { 
                "value": "C",
                 "begin":3,
                 "end":7,
             }     
    ],     
    "name": "test" 
}
```

I have about 6k documents in my Database and i want to unwind and group the values so i can count how many different values i have. After the unwind operation i have about 32 million documents.
I tried some variations of the aggregation but everytime its slow. I always need over 20 seconds.

I want to try the indexes but i cant creat and index that makes it any faster. I tried it with the MongoDB Compass app but i think im doing somethink wrong while i create the index.

Hope someone can help me.

Greetings

Comment: Indexes are beneficial when you are retrieving a small subset of documents. Here you seem to want to process the full collection (currently 6,000 documents) which means that the database must read and process all of them. No index is going to help with that. It looks like some aspects of this, including performance, were already discussed in [your previous question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73826409/mongodb-slow-unwind-and-group-aggregation)

Comment: Yes but i thought an index could be beneficial for the performance. Looks like my understanding of indexing is too bad. I think i have to accept the 'bad' runningtime.

Comment: If you must access all of the documents anyway (a collection scan), then adding a full index traversal on top of that will only slow things down. How often do you plan to run this operation? Is the goal just to count the number of unique `value`s or do you also need to sum up the values? What is your target performance and what functionality does this support in the application?

Comment: Its an application for data visualisation. The operation would be run once at the start of the application. I would count and sum the values. So i would have a sum operation in the count.

Comment: If this is going to be a synchronous operation that is going to happen when the application loads and the interface is unavailable until it completes, then it seems unlikely that you will be able to achieve the performance required to be successful with this approach.  You may need to consider restructuring your schema to help handle this frequent operation more efficiently and/or precomputing these results periodically to allow them to be quickly retrieved when the application launches.